# Error while displaying RTP stream packets from udp port on Gstreamer

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp, rtp, live-streaming

I am streaming a live webcam using VLC to darwin streaming server.

Then tried to play this live web cam feed on RTSP client using following

**GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch -vvv playbin uri=rtsp://172.19.91.21/channel.sdp**

Everthing works fine. output is coming on gstreamer window.

I have reflect all the packest from DSS to RTSP client as well as on a udp_port. But when i tried to play RTP stream using following command

**GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-0.10 -vvv udpsrc port=5000 multicast-iface="lo" multicast-group="172.19.91.20" buffer-size=1000000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264" do-timestamp=false ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink**

I am getting following errors

**0:00:07.108734201  7874  0x89d2a90 ERROR                 ffmpeg :0:: non-existing PPS referenced
0:00:07.108803500  7874  0x89d2a90 ERROR                 ffmpeg :0:: non-existing PPS 0 referenced
0:00:07.108824183  7874  0x89d2a90 ERROR                 ffmpeg :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:07.108840903  7874  0x89d2a90 ERROR                 ffmpeg :0:: no frame!
0:00:07.108859244  7874  0x89d2a90 WARN                  ffmpeg gstffmpegdec.c:2299:gst_ffmpegdec_frame: ffdec_h264: decoding error (len: -1, have_data: 0)**

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: How often is your web cam setup to send an IDR frame (keyframe)?

Comment: It is sending key frames after every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine after using following command:

**GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z2QAHqzZQKA9sBEAAAMAAQAAAwAyjxYtlg\=\=\,aOvjyyLA\=\"' ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264  ! xvimagesink sync=false**